# Cannot create New Simple Volume on a Free space of Extended partition

Tags: disk-management

I have a 2nd HDD connected to my PC. This HDD has only one Extended partition with a Free space and 3 Logical drives in it.

[image: Disk Management]

When I right click on Free space and try to create a New Simple Volume with all the defaults it gives me an error: "There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation."

How can I create Logical drive(s) on the Free space?

Comment: What version of Windows you have?

Comment: You right click the free space and select "Create new Simple Volume" that would create it in that space. Alternatively you could try to use `diskpart`.

Comment: @vembutech, I tried from both 8.1 and 10.

Comment: @Seth didn't I write that it gives an error?

Comment: @Seth After creating new simple volume only he is getting error "There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation". Read the question again.

Comment: Yes, but that's the correct way to do it. In addition I did mention an alternative, right? Would that get you the same error? The disk setup itself looks kind of strange with C: being a logical partition and indeed the whole drive having a single extended partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new volume that is not at the end of the chain of logical volumes inside an extended partition is a fairly complicated affair, as all the individual extended boot records (one for each logical volume) would have to be recalculated and rewritten. Evidently the Windows Disk Management program is not up to the task: it can only create a new volume at the end, and in this case there is no free/unallocated space there to work with.

It's quite possible that some non-Microsoft partitioning tool can do the job.

Comment: I made a backup of all my files and deleted all partitions on this HDD and created all from scratch using Windows Disk Management.